# Naked domain automaticly redirects but www not

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want to redirect my traffic to `HTTPS`

Coming from `myawesomesite.com` it redirects to `https://myawesomesite.com`, and coming from `http(s)://www.myawesomesite.com` it goes to `HTTP` or `HTTPS` based on the call.

What's wrong?
My virtualhost file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myawesomesite/public
    ServerName myawesomesite.com
    ServerAlias www.myawesomesite.com
        <Directory "/var/www/myawesomesite/public/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myawesomesite-error_log
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ="myawesomesite.com" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ="www.myawesomesite.com"
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to force SSL via Rewrite functions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Of course, remove your current code. Enjoy!

Update:

You can also do this which is better:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</virtualhost>
```